# Hypothesis testing: Should it be done on the transformed parameter or the non-transformed?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, binomial-distribution, bayes-factors

I want to compare two proportions, for example:

```
succN <- 2
d <- data.frame(pledge = c("yes", "no"),
s = c(succN, succN),n = c(100, 100))
```

I am using 'brms' and I've done it in two ways, without logistic transformation:

```
    m1 <- bf( s | trials(n) ~ 0 + pledge,
    family = binomial(link = "identity"))
    
    get_prior( m1,data = d)
    
    Prior <- set_prior("beta(1, 1)", class = "b", lb = 0, ub = 1)
    
 m1 <- brm(m1, prior = Prior,
        sample_prior = TRUE,
      iter = 2e4,data = d,cores = 4)
```

and with logistic transformation:

```
 p_sim <- rbeta(10000, 1, 1)
theta_sim <- log(p_sim / (1 - p_sim))
hist(p_sim)
hist(theta_sim)
c(mean(theta_sim), sd(theta_sim))


m1_log <- bf( s | trials(n) ~ 0 + pledge,
          family = binomial(link = "logit"))

get_prior( m1_log,data = d)


Prior <- set_prior("normal(0.0028, 1.837)", class = "b")

m1_log <- brm(m1_log, prior = Prior,
          sample_prior = TRUE,
          iter = 2e4,data = d,cores = 4)
```

I use 'hypothesis' function to see the Bayes factor. For the first model (w/o logistic transformation), there is one option:

```
h1 <- hypothesis(m1, "pledgeyes = pledgeno")
h1$hypothesis$Evid.Ratio
```

Which results in a value of 20 in favor of null.
For the model with logistic transformation, I have two options:

```
h1 <- hypothesis(m1_log, "pledgeyes = pledgeno")
h1$hypothesis$Evid.Ratio
h1 <- hypothesis(m1_log, "exp(pledgeyes)/(1+exp(pledgeyes)) = exp(pledgeno)/(1+exp(pledgeno))")
h1$hypothesis$Evid.Ratio
```

The first one compares the transformed parameters and the second one compares the proportions directly. The second one results in a similar Bayes factor as the model with no transformation, and personally I thought that the null of "proportions are equal" makes more sense than comparing the log odds. But I've seen differently in other places, specifically in a paper where the difference between the Bayes factor of the two models is discussed (https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.04909).

Which one is correct? Why are they different? In general, should the null be on the parameters that were transformed and used in the model?
(I used [this blog post](https://mvuorre.github.io/posts/2017-03-21-bayes-factors-with-brms/) )
Thanks!

Comment: Do your priors correspond? It doesn't look like it to me, but maybe I misunderstood the code (it's best not to use code to explain what you were trying to do because if there's any errors, you'll have errors of understanding conflated with errors of implementation; it also cuts down on the number of people that will correctly understand what you're doing)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Next time I'll separate the conceptual from the code. But to answer your question, I think yes, the two models are actually exactly the same (this was pointed out to me by Fabian Dablander after I posted the question). So there is something going on when we use "hypothesis(m1_log, "pledgeyes = pledgeno")" vs when we use "hypothesis(m1_log, "exp(pledgeyes)/(1+exp(pledgeyes)) = exp(pledgeno)/(1+exp(pledgeno))")"